# App crashes when Link All Assemblies enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am trying to reduce app size and enabled "Link All Assemblies", but my app crashes with following error

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type Japam.Core.ViewModels.MantraasViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information

I tried

```
--linkskip=mvvmcross.platform.ios 
--linkskip=mvvmcross.core  
--linkskip=mvvmcross.platform
```

but no luck, kept preserve attribute at assembly level of my core pcl project.
Also added a couple of more methods in LinkerPleaseIncludefile

```
public void Include(MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjection injection)
{
    injection = new MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxPropertyInjection();
}

public void Include(MvxDefaultViewModelLocator locator)
{
    locator = new MvxDefaultViewModelLocator();
}
```

but no use, could somebody help me find out what is missing

[image: This is what I see]

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type
>   Japam.Core.ViewModels.MantraasViewModel from locator
>   MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information
>   ---> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Problem creating viewModel of type MantraasViewModel --->
>   MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to
>   construct MantraasViewModel --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to
>   resolve parameter for parameter sqliteConnectionFactory of type
>   IMvxSqliteConnectionFactory when creating
>   Japam.Core.Services.DataServices.MantraService
>         at MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues
>   (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor)
>   [0x00036] in D:\git\MvvmCross\MvvmCross\Platform\Platform\IoC\

Comment: What exactly does the `InnerException` say?

Comment: InnerException is not shown, it just shows that

Comment: If you select continue and when your app disconnects from the debugger you should be able to see the entire exception in the output window. Which will include the inner exception.

Comment: Nothing is there in output window it just says check inner exception :(

Comment: The easiest way to narrow down this issue is to see if this is a linker issue. First try setting to "Don't Link", confirm if the behavior is gone and then work your way up. Typically these issues are because your code is being linked away. A custom linker configuration file is the best way to control that. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/custom_linking/

Comment: I got it, after removing the constructor dependency, updated the error. Its sqllite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the issue, it's SQLite problem so I added below three commands and it started working hope this helps someone else

```
--linkskip=MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite 
--linkskip=SQLite-net 
--linkskip=MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.iOS
```

I should kept SQLite earlier it self my last project I did kept SQLite but forgot this time